# How to convert a Dictionary containing values as comma seperated strings into a Collection of KeyValuePairs?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary like:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "key1", "value1,value2,value3" },
        { "key2", "value4,value5" }
    }
```

How can I convert to a `List` of `KeyValuePair` of following nature:

```
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myList = n List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        { "key1", "value1" },
        { "key1", "value2" },
        { "key1", "value3" },
        { "key2", "value4" },
        { "key2", "value5" }
    }
```

Sorry for possible unclearness in the question topic.

Comment: Try this : List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myList = myDict.Keys.Select(x => myDict[x].Split(new char[] {','}).Select(y => new KeyValuePair<string,string>(x,y))).SelectMany(y => y).ToList();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key to this conversion is `SelectMany` method:

```
var res = myDict
    .SelectMany(p => p.Value.Split(',').Select(s => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(p.Key, s)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: it wont compile

Answer (score 1):

Without using linq,

```
  public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GenerateKeyValuePair(Dictionary<string,string> dict) {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> List = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        foreach (var item in dict)
        {
                string[] values = item.Value.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    List.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Key, values[i].ToString()));
                }
        }
        return List;
    }
```

Hope helps, (btw Linq is the shortest answer)

Comment: the `if (item.Value.Contains(','))` is useless. You can remove the `if` altogether and your code will work just as well